# Pygal.maps.world.World() is not interactive

Tags: pygal

I am trying to build an interactive Pygal worldmap. I posted my code below, but any ideas why the numbers are not showing up when I hover over the map? Thanks!

```
import pygal
wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.title = "Americas"
wm.add('North America',{'ca': 320161819,'mx': 115405161,'us': 301018101})

wm.render_to_file('americas.svg')
```

Comment: What are you using to view the .svg file?

Comment: I was using chrome, but I got the problem fixed. Thanks